# Target sibling descendant in TailwindCSS

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm writing code for a dropdown menu using Tailwind, and want to change the pointer-event class of the `<a>` elements, which are children of a peer to the button itself. I use `peer` already to alter the opacity of the parent to the `<a>` elements, but I cant figure out how to alter the properties of the `<a>` elements themselves based on the focus of the button element. Currently, the `pointer-events-none` is applied to the `<a>` elements, and I want it to toggle when the button is focused.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div
  class="w-full py-12 mt-3 border border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700 rounded-xl flex flex-col justify-center items-center"
>
  <div class="w-48 flex flex-col text-left">
    <button
      id="basicDropdownButton"
      class="peer flex items-center h-10 px-4 font-semibold rounded-md transition-all shadow-md text-white bg-violet-500 hover:bg-violet-400 dark:hover:bg-violet-600 border border-violet-400"
    >
      Dropdown
      <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-down text-sm ml-auto"></i>
    </button>
    <div
      id="basicDropdownMenu"
      class="peer w-full my-1 flex flex-col justify-center items-center rounded-md transition-all bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-700 border border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-500 opacity-0 peer-focus:opacity-100"
    >
      <a
        href=""
        class="py-2 w-full pointer-events-none text-black/[0.86] dark:text-white font-semibold px-4 hover:bg-gray-200 dark:hover:bg-gray-600"
        >Link 1</a
      >
      <a
        href=""
        class="py-2 w-full pointer-events-none text-black/[0.86] dark:text-white font-semibold px-4 hover:bg-gray-200 dark:hover:bg-gray-600"
        >Link 2</a
      >
      <a
        href=""
        class="py-2 w-full pointer-events-none text-black/[0.86] dark:text-white font-semibold px-4 hover:bg-gray-200 dark:hover:bg-gray-600"
        >Link 3</a
      >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this almost as soon as I posted it. It doesn't target the children of the peer ( the `<a>` elements) specifically, but it does what I need it to do. Simple fix was to apply the `pointer-events-none` to the parent of the `<a>` elements, which would then apply to them and also be easily togglable. I know this doesn't answer the question exactly, but it is a solution that worked for me and may help others.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div
  class="w-full py-12 mt-3 border border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-700 rounded-xl flex flex-col justify-center items-center"
>
  <div class="w-48 flex flex-col text-left">
    <button
      id="basicDropdownButton"
      class="peer flex items-center h-10 px-4 font-semibold rounded-md transition-all shadow-md text-white bg-violet-500 hover:bg-violet-400 dark:hover:bg-violet-600 border border-violet-400"
    >
      Dropdown
      <i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-down text-sm ml-auto"></i>
    </button>
    <div
      id="basicDropdownMenu"
      class="peer w-full my-1 flex flex-col justify-center items-center rounded-md transition-all bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-700 border border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-500 opacity-0 peer-focus:opacity-100 pointer-events-none peer-focus:pointer-events-auto"
    >
      <a
        href=""
        class="py-2 w-full text-black/[0.86] dark:text-white font-semibold px-4 hover:bg-gray-200 dark:hover:bg-gray-600"
        >Link 1</a
      >
      <a
        href=""
        class="py-2 w-full text-black/[0.86] dark:text-white font-semibold px-4 hover:bg-gray-200 dark:hover:bg-gray-600"
        >Link 2</a
      >
      <a
        href=""
        class="py-2 w-full text-black/[0.86] dark:text-white font-semibold px-4 hover:bg-gray-200 dark:hover:bg-gray-600"
        >Link 3</a
      >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not valid html.